# ASP.NET VB one of two field validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have two text fields. The user needs to fill out either one or the other or both.

I found this plugin but it's in C# and I have to use VB for the project and my attempts to translate it have all failed:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13502/Multiple-Fields-Validator-An-ASP-NET-Validation-Co

Is there an easy way to get this done or am I stuck programming a CustomValidator to handle it?

Comment: What's wrong with the CustomValidator? Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: How have you tried to translate? Have you used one of the many online translators. The one I use has never let me down (unless there was an actual error in the C# in the first place)

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/               you can convert your c# coding to vb.net here.

Comment: Maybe I'm just converting it wrong. When you download the demo it comes with the .dll which is compiled in C#. In the "source download" I translated all the .cs files to .vb but I need to compile it to a .dll properly which I think I'm messing up. Is there a tutorial on how to take the C# project file and make it a VB project file to compile it? I'm a web designer not programmer so 99% of my coding is html, css, & jquery. I got in a little over my head taking this project on.

Comment: Can you not just use the dll by adding it as a reference in your VB project? Why bother translating it at all?

Comment: Does it matter that the reference will be in C# when I was told specifically to use VB for the project? I'm new to this type of programming so maybe I just don't understand how the references work in terms of how it interacts with the rest of the coding.

Comment: Your project will still be coded in VB, just one of the dependencies will be coded in C#. You'll use many dependencies in your project, e.g. the .net framework, that won't be coded in VB :) but you'll never have to look at the code, unless you need to debug it for some reason.